# Is there a way to tell git which lines to treat as modified in the diff?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I've modified a file (in Ruby, as it happens, but my question is really about Git) by moving a method up the file. Here's a pseudo-diff:

```rb
class A
  # some stuff

+ def b
+ end
+
  private

  def a
  end
- 
- def b
- end
end
```

However, git insists on framing this change as:

```rb
class A
  # some stuff
 
- private
-
- def a
- end
-
  def b
  end
+
+ private
+
+ def a
+ end
end
```

ie. it sees the `private` keyword and method `a` as having moved *down* instead.

This is equally correct in terms of describing how the file changed, but it doesn't convey the *intent* of the change nearly as well. It's potentially a bit confusing even: the result of the change is to make method `b` a public method, but this diff makes it look as if it was method `a` that has changed.

I think Git has chosen this diff because method `a` is slightly shorter than method `b`, so this ends up producing a slightly smaller diff. However, in terms of making my commit easily comprehensible it would be preferable if the diff looked more like the first example here, to make it clear that the relevant change was to method `b`.

My question is: is there any way of manually editing the hunks that Git has chosen when I stage this change, so I can create a commit whose diff looks like the first example rather than the second one?

Comment: This is a limitation of command line diffs. Using a GUI diff tool is the better option in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: is there any way of manually editing the hunks that Git has chosen when I stage this change, so I can create a commit whose diff looks like the first example rather than the second one?

No; commits do not store *diffs*, they store *snapshots* of the file(s) at a current point in time.  So you cannot "create a commit" whose diff looks a certain way; instead, the diff is created instantaneously, when you view it.

That means that each git client, when it views your commit, would need to understand how to display the diff to your liking.  There is no such mechanism to tell git clients how you would prefer it to be seen.

There are a variety of options that the *viewer* of your commit can use to indicate how *they want to see* the change, but there is no mechanism that *you* can use to tell them how *you want them to see* the change.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had thought that individual commits contained the modified lines (ie. more or less what you see when you do `git show`), so this has given me a clearer understanding of how Git actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `git diff --help`.  There are many options for specifying which diff algorithm git will use.

```
   --diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}
       Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:

       default, myers
           The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the default.

       minimal
           Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.

       patience
           Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.

       histogram
           This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support low-occurrence common elements".
```

I don't know what the differences between them are, but I would start looking there.